# How do i pass string with escape characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, escaping

There are many such questions here,but none of them was able to solve my question.I am trying to implement a simple toggle switch between "See more" and "See less" in SWT Browser in a java application.I am using this code with some changes
http://jsfiddle.net/8u2jF/

My code would be something like

```
<div>
    <p id="textArea"><!-- This is where I want to additional text--></p>
</div>


<a id="toggleButton" onclick="toggleText(encodeURI('hsd\\nhe'));" href="javascript:void(0);">See More</a>

var status = "less";

function toggleText(s)
{
    var text="Here is some text that I want added to the HTML file";

    if (status == "less") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML=decodeURI(s);
        document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "See Less";
        status = "more";
    } else if (status == "more") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "See More";
        status = "less"
    }
}
```

But when i run this \n is not taken as a new line character?How do i make Javascript understand that it is newline character?

I will be using this script in java SWT application and invoke it using SWT Browser.I will pass a string as a parameter which might contain any escape character.How do i handle them?

Comment: change `\n` to `<br/>`

Comment: but what about \t and \r? I actually have to a pass a string which will have escape characters.

Comment: I am using this in a java app and i will invoke this script using browser function and pass a string as aparameter.That string will be having such escape characters.then,how do i handle it?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML there is no such elements as `\t`, `\n`, `\r`. Use `<br/>` for newline, `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` for `\t` (or better css `margin-right`).

```js
function addText(text) {
  $('span').append("<br/>First line goes here <br/> Second line goes here");
}

function replaceText(text) {
  $('span').append(
    text.replace("\\n", '<br/>')
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onClick="replaceText('<br/>First Line\\nSecond Line')">Click to add and replace</div>
<div onClick="addText('<br/>First line goes here <br/> Second line goes here')">Click to see magic</div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: I am using this in a java app and i will invoke this script using browser function and pass a string as aparameter.That string will be having such escape characters.then,how do i handle it?

Comment: @user3425344 I updated answer's example. `\r`, `\t` will be ignored by browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
toggleText(encodeURI('hsd\nhe'));
```

(with a new line \n)

and not

```
toggleText(encodeURI('hsd\\nhe'));
```

(the first \ prevents the second one to be interpreted)

the result will be

```
<p id="textArea">hsd
he</p>
```

So there's a new line in the source code but this is not visible in the html rendering
If you want a new line in the rendering, you need to add html markups

Comment: If i use onclick="toggleText(encodeURI('hsd\nhe'));" .I get the result as hsd nhe I just tried it on fiddle.

Comment: Yes, as I said the new line is in the source code but you can't see it in the rendering because you can add spaces or new lines it doesn't matter for the html rendering.
You can try with `toggleText(encodeURI('hsd\n\n\n\n\n\nhe'));`
Same rendering (html) but if you inspect the source you can see :
`<p id="textArea">hsd





he</p>`
and not
`<p id="textArea">hsd he</p>`

Comment: If you want to add a line in the html rendering, you can :
- add a `<br />` between each line
or
- encapsulate each line in an html markup : `<p>First Line</p><p>Second Line</p>`